# Create a smaller apk file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, size, apk, adt

How can I generate a smaller .apk in Eclipse [ADT-plugin].
My apk is ~1mb big even when I only have the standard "Hello World" string.
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a bare minimal size you have to remove all unnecessary libraries (e.g. support library, its useless to just display a Hello World), graphic assets/resources like large dpi launcher icons and other resources that are not absolutely required.
For example, I just created a project that targets Donut (API v4) and displays a "Hello World". The APK of this project turned out to be just about 42 KB.

Overall, you need to avoid adding unnecessary libraries, asset files and resource files (especially images/audio) that your project doesn't actually need or use, and use ProGuard to remove unused code.